# How to change Object value on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs

Im populating/inserting `jsonObjects[i].type` in a `menu` with a `div` called `#changetotypes`. Im getting values `r`, `c` and `e` from `jsonObjects[i].type` in a menu, know I wanna be able to click on does value `r`, `c` and `e` and change the values to the clicked value. Know I can click on a object and It is displaying the value `r`, `c` or `e`.
So If I click on a object It gets/display the value `jsonObjects[i].type` `r`, `c` or `e` in a menu that the object have. Know how can I change my clicked objects value example from `r` to `c`?

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Typs</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span id="currenttype" title=""></span></a>
                <ul id="changetotypes"></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
</li>

function populateTypes() {

    for(i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length; i++) {

        if(availableTypes.indexOf(jsonObjects[i].type) < 0) {

            availableTypes.push(jsonObjects[i].type);
            $("#changetotypes").append('<li><a href="#">' + jsonObjects[i].type + '</a></li>');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/73UyJ/2/)

Comment: @Givi Hi! Something like your code Yes... I can not get your code to work, Its says ele (ele.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", str);) is null. But in your working code sample its something like that Yes.

Comment: Made your own jsFiddle, and I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following [(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/LNwQk/1/). Assuming jsonObjects comes from somewhere else.

```
function populateTypes() {
    var availableTypes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length; i++) {
        if(availableTypes.indexOf(jsonObjects[i].type) < 0) {
            availableTypes.push(jsonObjects[i].type);
            $('<li><a href="#">' + jsonObjects[i].type + '</a></li>')
            .data('type', jsonObjects[i].type)
            .on('click', function(){ $('#currenttype').text($(this).data('type')); })
            .appendTo('#changetotypes');
        }
    }
}
```

Here when we create the <li/> element for a specific type, we add a click handler at the same time that changes the text of the currenttype element.

We store the type we want to change currenttype to in the data of our <li/> element so we don't have to worry about [closures in the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem), but there are other ways to solve that problem as well, like creating a function that returns a function (see link) or using the contents of the <a/> element (as in $('a', $(this)).text()).

Comment: Great. Is it something that should be changed in the answer here for future viewers, or does it only have to do with the rest of your code which was left out for the purpose of this question?

Comment: The answer has to do with the rest of my code... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a click event listener for each #changetotypes children's, then change the inner html of that child.

You may have to give an id to each children to know how to get a reference for each one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, Im gonna try your suggest.